# Android: NullPointer when clicking on ListItem calling showContextMenuForChild

Tags: android, listview

I have the following problem:

I display items on a ListView and I want to display a ContextMenu for the item, if the user clicks it. So what I did is, adding an OnItemClickListener with the following code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (view == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (sessionListView == null) {
        sessionListView = (SessionListView) findViewById(R.id.sessionlist);
    }

    if (view != null) {
        sessionListViewSelected = position;
        sessionListViewSelectedKey = (String) authList.keySet().toArray()[position];

        sessionListView.showContextMenuForChild(view);
    }
}
```

Now, SOMETIMES I get following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.AdapterView.getPositionForView(AdapterView.java:581)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:1926)
    at de.trier.infsec.koch.droidsheep.activities.ListenActivity.onItemClick(ListenActivity.java:322)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1849)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does anybody have an suggestion, what could be the problem for that?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you changing the contents of the ListView after it's displayed?

Comment: Yes, there is another thread, which changes the ListAdapter and a handler refreshing the list... Might this cause the issues?

Comment: Here is some info about `getPositionForView()` throwing `NullPointerException` with an explanation why it occurs:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3175

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably occurs because you are updating ListAdapter from separate thread. You should only mutate UI elements (or classes that UI elements depend on) [from UI thread](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Try this to update your data on UI thread:

```
listAdapter.getView().post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      // change listAdapter here
    }
  });
```